# Return an object with an update data, that is pass in to a public static function

Tags: actionscript-3, return, static-functions

How can I return an object with an update data, that is pass in to a public static function?

```
GetDate.dayName(MyDate.setDate(1984,3))
//MyDate with new info (year, month) will be pass into GetDate.dayName


package hwang.time
{

public class MyDate
{
    public static var getYear:Number;
    public static var getMonth:Number;

    public static function setDate(year:Number, month:Number = 1):Object
    {
        getYear = year;
        getMonth = month
        verify()
        return null
    }

    private static function verify():void
    {
        //something
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What you're trying to do is not clear. Which function are you trying to call, and what should it return?

Comment: i'm trying to pass MyDate.getYear into GetDate, after I verified it in MyDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static function setDate(year:Number, month:Number = 1):MyDate

    {
        getYear = year;
        getMonth = month
        verify()

        verify()

        return new MyDate
    }
```

Here's what I come up with.Thanks for helping anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... not sure what's the difficulty. Have you tried simply accessing `getYear` from `verify`? Unless I'm missing something, that should just work:

```
private static function verify():void
{
    trace(getYear); // print the year or do something else with it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

get rid of the static functions and create a "normal" `Date` object `new MyDate(1984,3);` and then verify the date iside the constructor:

```
package hwang.time
{
    public class MyDate
    {
        private var _year:Number;
        private var _month:Number;

        public function MyDate(year:Number, month:Number = 1)
        {
            _year = year;
            _month = month;
            _verify();
        }

        private function _verify():void
        {
            //something
        }
    }
}
```

and instead of having another static function returning you the name of the day, add a public function to the `MyDate` class:

```
public function getDayName():String
{
    return "<name>";
}
```

whole snippet

```
var mydate:MyDate = new MyDate(1984, 3);
trace(mydate.getDayName());
```